# Can't reflash esp8266 - 12E after many attemptions

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wifi, esp8266

I have the following circuit for updating custom firmware to my esp8266-12e module. I've tried many variations for GPIO0, GPIO2, but none of them works. I use the Arduino IDE to make hex files, and then I upload the binary using esptool.py with the following command: `python esptool.py --baud 115200 -p /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x00 /Users/blahblah/Documents/ArduinoBinary/WiFiWebServer.cpp.bin` 
[image]

Comment: I was unable to get mine to flash with resistors either, and had to connect the GPIOs directly to the source. My board does look quite a bit different though.

Answer (score 1):

Try following [ESP8266: flash module firmware](http://dominicm.com/esp8266-flash-module-firmware/) post. I've used those steps on ESP-07 and ESP-01 module several times. There should be no need for resistors unless specifically required by ESP-12 module. If it still fails try to eliminate software issues as the problem by using windows flasher as per the post as that is known to work. Also do not use a breadboard as it can cause issues.

Here's a working schematic for ESP-07 module and by the looks of it it should be the same for ESP-12:

[image]